# C++: move / forwarding / rvalue delegation shenanigans

Tags: c++, move, semantics

Try running this test program :

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A()                          { std::cout << "empty constructor" << std::endl; }
    A(const A &a)                { std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    A(A &&a)                     { std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl;  }
    ~A()                         { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }
    A &operator=(const A &o)     { std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl; return *this; }
    A &operator=(A &&o)          { std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl; return *this; }
};

A outside;

template <typename U>
void bar(U &&a) {
    outside = std::forward<U>(a);
}

void foo(A &&a) {
    bar(a);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    foo(A());
    return 0;
}
```

On my compiler, I think GCC 4.4.1, the output is:

```
empty constructor
empty constructor
copy assignment // what??
destructor
destructor
```

In my opinion the third line is strange. Why is `outside` copying `a` in `bar` instead of moving it? In other words,hy does `foo` use the `bar(A &a)` instantiation of `bar` instead of `bar(A &&a)`?

I should mention that this problem is easily fixable by changing `foo` to

```
template <typename U>
void foo(U &&a) {
    bar(std::forward<U>(a));
}
```

whereupon the move assignment operator is used instead.

In my code I have a lot of delegation methods and I'd hate to have to stick them all in a .h file and make templates for them. Is there another way of telling the compiler or making it understand that `a` is used as an rvalue in `foo`?

**EDIT:** A few people pointed out this change:

```
void foo(U &&a) {
    bar(std::move(a));
}
```

I was too slow to indicate that I want `foo` to be able to accept both:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    foo(A());
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A a;
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The suggested code will incorrectly steal, in the second case, `a`'s resources in `main` where it should be used as a reference.

Comment: Because `a` in `foo` is an lvalue. You need `bar(std::move(a));`. I'm looking for a good duplicate.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain the problem more clearly. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do different things for lvalues nd rvalues, you can implement two overloads of `foo` instead of using the template.

Comment: I'm fine with using templates instead of overloading; the problem is really just that I have a stack of 10 functions all using `A&&` and I'd have to template all of them to use `std::forward`. Is there really no other way?

Comment: @bombax: There is really no other way. If you want to have a method that forwards then you need to either duplicate that method or template it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense. You say you want `foo(a);` to be accepted, but your original signature `void foo(A &&a) {` does not accept that

Comment: Matt Mcnabb, it compiles and runs fine on my compiler. IINW `void foo(A &&a)` accepts both an rvalue `A&&` and an lvalue `A&`.

Comment: @bombax If that is true then [your compiler is broken](http://goo.gl/LA8NHp)

Comment: I'm not sure what to say: http://imgur.com/dR6wrzQ Maybe some compilers do implicit casting? Changing the call to `foo((A&&)a)` compiles.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that either you're using a broken compiler, or the code being compiled isn't the same as the code onscreen (sometimes codeblocks can do that if you don't Ctrl-Shift-S before compiling)

Comment: `foo((A&&)a)` is the same as `foo( std::move(a) )`

Comment: Very strange it must be a broken compiler then or something. It behaves a bit strange, as in, I can't specify `std=c++11` for it but can still use `unordered_set` except I can't use its `reserve` but can use its `rehash`... ??? It says "gcc version 4.4.1 (TDM-2 mingw32) " EDIT: Try changing your link to gcc 4.4.7 then it works!

Comment: "I can't specify std=c++11" - that strongly suggests the compiler is pre-C++11. You really will need to update your compiler.

Comment: In case it is still unclear: even if you wrote `foo( (A&&)a )`  (which is what your version of g++ is doing), then `foo` does not have the information about whether it was called with a temporary object or not; you have to either copy (`bar(a)`) or steal resources (`bar(std::move(a))`).   The proper way to steal only from rvalues (without using a template) is to have a pair of overloads `void foo(A& a) { bar(a); }  void foo(A&& a) { bar(std::move(a)); }`

Comment: This is perfectly clear, thanks!

Comment: An alternative to the overload pair is `template<typename T> void foo(T &&a) { bar(std::forward(a)); }` because forwarding references can deduce reference types; but I guess you didn't do this because you could have just called `bar` in the first place :)

Comment: Yes, or rather, in my actual program, there's a stack of like 10 functions all taking `A&&` all delegating and doing other things and I really didn't want to template them all, but now that I know of all this, I'll either reconsider the design or template them all, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Inside your foo function it should be:
`bar(std::move(a))` because the parameter `a` is at that point an lvalue.

Comment: I've edited the question to illustrate what I wanted more clearly, thanks!